# Kivy (python) can't found module VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, kivy

I try to use camera from kivy (1.9.1) base - python 3.4 (platform - Windows 10)
 I have installed opencv (it's working. I tried import it and all just ok.) but when I try to launch some camera example I got error
**videocapture - ImportError: No module named 'VideoCapture'**

When I tried import it *from VideoCapture import Device*   it's failed

I can't found some possible way to resolve this issue. Please, help me someone. I fight with this issue 4 days and I stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried to install that module? Maybe it's [this one](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Thanks for answer. I didn't install this module separatedly from opencv because I thought that it's native dependency of opencv. Thanks, I will try to install it for kivy. (But I saw that this module have dependency of python 2.7  but I use 3.4  I should reinstall all stuff to 2.7 python or maybe some another way exist?)

Comment: I rewrited VideoCapture.py to newest 3.4 format but I have issue with import vidcap module.   
Got error: Failed load Dll.  %1 it's not win32 app

Comment: Leaved Kivy camera in rest and peace and got video from native python opencv (3.4 python).